# Xcode9 beta - Error adding openssl & library not found for -lcrypto

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcode9-beta

I am trying to add open SSL universal via cocoapods, it's installing it but on terminal, I am getting this message

> The CustomerApp [Debug] target overrides the LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS
>   build setting defined in Pods/Target Support
>   Files/Pods-CustomerApp/Pods-CustomerApp.debug.xcconfig. This can lead
>   to problems with the CocoaPods installation
>       - Use the $(inherited) flag, or
>       - Remove the build settings from the target

another problem is in XCode (9 beta) build failed with this error

> library not found for -lcrypto..

I am really dying because of this, have tried everything possible but no success I tried manually adding OpenSSL by downloading from site and setting the path in build settings by doing that it doesn't show error but in my swift file when import OpenSSL it says no such module.

please help me!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is looking for libcrypto.a library, can you search through your project see if it exists. When you download the OpenSSL library, it should have the library along with a bundle of header files.